# finding numeric pattern in character vector containing numeric digits separated by space

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I got a data frame which containg a column containing codes separated by space.
And I want to search those ids by applying "<" or ">" etc arithmatic operaters.

Input data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Id=c(101, 102,103), Codes=c("1 2 3", "2 4 5", "4 5"))
```

I tried finding id's who have codes greater than 3.
so that I can get 102 and 103 as output.

```
df[df$Codes > "3", ]
```

but this is giving me 103 id.
what I am missing??

Comment: for now, you're comparing strings and, alphabetically, the strings "4 5" is the only one after the string "3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Codes), "\\s+"), function(x) any(as.numeric(x)>3)), ]
#   Id Codes
#2 102 2 4 5
#3 103   4 5
```

---

Or use `grep`

```
df[grep("[4-9]", df$Codes),] 
#   Id Codes
#2 102 2 4 5
#3 103   4 5
```

If we need only the "Id"

```
df$Id[grep("[4-9]", df$Codes)] 
#[1] 102 103
```

Comment: This is really great. Thanks @akrun. But I have one query, cant we do it in a simple way just same as %like% operater does:

df$Codes %like% '3'

same way
df$Codes <'3'

Comment: @indra_patil It is a string.  So, the one simple way is using `grep`